# DropDownMenu.SelectedIndex causing error even though value exists

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a drop down list that is populated from a database table:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="userNameDropDown" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
    DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="PK_User" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [Name], [PK_User] FROM [User] ORDER BY [Name]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

When I assign a specific row as default it works fine:

```
userNameDropDown.SelectedIndex = 3;
```

However when I use this dropdown:

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="catagoryDropDownListEdit" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5"
        DataTextField="Catagory" DataValueField="PK_SupportCatagory">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource5" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [PK_SupportCatagory], [Catagory] FROM [SupportCatagory]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And try:

```
catagoryDropDownListEdit.SelectedIndex = 1;
```

I get this error:

```
'catagoryDropDownListEdit' has a SelectedIndex which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'catagoryDropDownListEdit' has a SelectedIndex which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value
```

Here is a pic that shows there are infact values:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/akNaf.png

Comment: at which event you are setting its index value

Comment: It causes the same error everywhere. It's actually when a user clicks 'edit' on a gridview but if I move it to Page_Load the same error occurs.

Comment: before setting index do dropdownid.databind()

Comment: databind() worked. Thank you very much. Could you explain why to this noob?

Comment: See this answer...below...for explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> DataBinding Raised after the control's PreRender event, which occurs
>   after the page's PreRender event. (This applies to controls whose
>   DataSourceID property is set declaratively. Otherwise the event
>   happens when you call the control's DataBind method.)

So to set selected inedex of dropdownlist on page load you have to call `DataBind()` method like this...

```
dropdownlist1.DataBind()
```

After this you can set the index.But if you set before binding than it will give error because there no item in dropdownlist.